# Запятая после и

Tags: запятые

Сегодня зарегистрирована новая организация, и(,) дай Бог, чтобы это...
Нужна ли зпт в скобках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Союзом "и" здесь присоединяется сложноподчинённое предложение, главная часть которого (дай Бог) эквивалентна пожеланию "Надо надеяться" или "Было бы хорошо".

Answer (score -1):

"дай Бог" в данном случае - междометие, а они всегда отделяются
https://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/155-zap-19-36

Comment: И от союза тоже?